# React filter two arrays with if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array:

```
items: [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: honda,
    isOpened: false
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: suzuki,
    isOpened: false
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: audi,
    isOpened: false
  }
]
```

And this array:

```
orders: [
  {
    _id: 123,
    user: Mark,
    ordersName: honda
  },
  {
    _id: 124,
    user: Angela,
    ordersName: honda
  },
  {
    _id: 125,
    user: Ana,
    ordersName: suzuki
  }
]
```

I'm using this code:

```
const dd = this.props.items.filter(({ name: name1, isOpened = isOpened }) =>
  this.props.ordersList.some(
    ({ ordersName: name2 }) => name1 === name2 || isOpened === true
  )
)
```

That work OK. But when there is no orders for specific item in database, when I click on order button, a div with item data is not showing, it shows only when I have orders. When website is loaded if there is some orders, a div with items and orders list is shown, but when there is no orders when I click on open/show item It is not showing up.

I'm using a map on const dd, like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    {dd.map(response => {
      response.isOpened = true;
      return (
        <div className="panel" key={response._id}>
          <h1>{response.name}</h1>
          <div>
            {this.props.ordersList.map(res => {
              if (response.name == res.ordersName) {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <h3>{res.ordersName}</h3>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if I explained this well.

Comment: Hello @Saban, I know nothing about React but the code you wrote is not javascript (Im saying this because those are the tags you choose). I adapted it but Iḿ not sure if you are trying to achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/gal007/64jo3asr/11/ Can you add a fiddle so we can play better with your solution? (you can add the react version you are using to jsfiddle)

Comment: I have already been using that code. It works well when i click on add new order. But on page load, i need to filter is there orders, and isOpen equals to true.

Comment: check the code I wrote in the fiddle. Open the console, you will see the filtered orders

Comment: OK. Lets say this code you wrote is good. But how can I now filter orders. I need to know if there is orders for an item, to be automaticaly displayed when page is loaded. Thats what I need.

Comment: I have solved my issue with this code:
const dd1= this.props.items.filter(({name: name1}) => this.props.orders.some(({ordersName: name2}) => name1 === name2));
   dd1.map(itms=>{
       itms.isOpened=true
   })
   const dd=this.props.items.filter(itm=>{
    return itm.isOpened==true
   })

Comment: Is there any way to write that code in less lines? Or even in one line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this seems more logic if want to say the restaurant is `open` and there is `some order` in case there is no order you can just display a message like `There is no order`

```js
const items = [{
    _id: 1,
    name: "honda",
    isOpened: true
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "suzuki",
    isOpened: true
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "audi",
    isOpened: false
  }
]

const orders = [{
    _id: 123,
    user: "Mark",
    ordersName: "honda"
  },
  {
    _id: 124,
    user: "Angela",
    ordersName: "honda"
  },
  {
    _id: 125,
    user: "Ana",
    ordersName: "suzuki"
  }
]

const dd = items.filter(({
    name: name1,
    isOpened
  }) => {
    if (isOpened)
      return orders.filter(
        ({
          ordersName: name2
        }) => name1 === name2
      )
  }

)


console.log(dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue with this code:

```
const dd1= this.props.items.filter(({name: name1}) => this.props.orders.some(({ordersName: name2}) => name1 === name2)); dd1.map(itms=>{ itms.isOpened=true }) const dd=this.props.items.filter(itm=>{ return itm.isOpened==true })
```

Is there any way to write that code in less lines? Or even in one line of code?